# Why is this not a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Just trying to figure this problem out.Which one of the 10 axioms does (x,y) x,y E R not satisfy. I've tried associative multiplication and associative addition as answers but been incorrect

> Let $V$ be the set $\{(x,y)∣x,y\in\mathbb R\}$ with addition operation $\oplus$ defined by $$(x_1,y_1)\oplus (x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_1y_2)$$ and scalar multiplication $\odot$ defined by $$\alpha\odot (x,y)=(x,0).$$ Show that $V$ is not a vector space by determining which of the $10$ vector space axioms are not true for $V$.

Comment: are you searching for vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}?$ It seem to be. So, if you are, it is, indeed, a vector space.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Let V be the set {(x,y)∣x,y∈R} with addition operation ⊕ defined by (x1,y1)⊕(x2,y2)=(x1+x2,y1y2) and scalar multiplication ⊙ defined by α⊙(x,y)=(x,0). Show that V is not a vector space by determining which of the 10 vector space axioms are not true for V.

Comment: One of the big issues with this set is that $(x_1,y_1)$ with $y_1\neq 0$ cannot be expressed in the form $\alpha\odot v$ for any $\alpha\in \Bbb R$ or $v\in V$.  The whole scalar multiplication bit seems completely off.  We like in vector spaces for things to work like $v\oplus v=(1\odot v)\oplus (1\odot v) = (1+1)\odot v = 2\odot v$

Comment: @JMoravitz Does y1 not have to equal 0 because any scalar multiplied by 0 is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which "ten" axioms you are using, as many of the references on my shelf only refer to eight axioms.  Regardless, one of the biggest issues with the set with operations as defined above is how scalar multiplication works.

Given $1\in \Bbb F$, the multiplicative element of the underlying scalar field, we want to have $1\odot v = v$ for all $v\in V$.  This however is not the case here.  For example:

$$1\odot (3,5) = (3,0)\neq (3,5)$$

We also want scalar addition to be distributive over scalar multiplication.  We want $(\alpha + \beta)\odot v = (\alpha\odot v) \oplus (\beta \odot v)$.  This also fails.  For example:

$$(3,0)=(2)\odot (3,5) = (1+1)\odot (3,5)$$

$$(1\odot (3,5))\oplus (1\odot (3,5)) = (3,0)\oplus (3,0) = (6,0)$$

$$\text{however}~(3,0)\neq (6,0)~\text{so}~(1+1)\odot(3,5)\neq (1\odot(3,5))\oplus (1\odot(3,5))$$

We do in fact have an identity element when looking at $V$ as a possible group, namely $(0,1)$ since we have $(x,y)\oplus (0,1) = (x+0,y\cdot 1) = (x,y) = (0,1)\oplus (x,y)$

We do not however have the ability to find the inverse element for every $v$, in particular if the second entry of $v$ is zero.  We wanted to have the ability to say that $v+(-v) = (0,1)$ since $(0,1)$ is our identity element.  However:

$$(1,0)\oplus (x,y) = (1+x,0)\neq (0,1)$$ for all choices of $x$ and $y$.

All of the following happen to be fine: associativity of vector addition ($v\oplus (u\oplus w) = (v\oplus u)\oplus w$), commutativity of vector addition ($v\oplus u = u\oplus v$), existence of identity for vector addition ($\exists e$ such that $v\oplus e = v = e\oplus v$), compatibility of scalar multiplication: ($\alpha \odot (\beta \odot v) = (\alpha \cdot \beta) \odot v$), even distributivity of scalar multiplication over vector addition ($\alpha\odot (v\oplus u) = (\alpha\odot v)\oplus (\alpha \odot u)$).

The axioms (*from the list I'm looking at*) that fail are: identity element of scalar multiplication, distributivity of scalar multiplication over scalar addition, inverse elements of vector addition.

Depending on your list of *ten* axioms, there could be others (for example $0\odot v = e$ where $0$ is the additive identity in the scalar field, and $e$ is the additive identity in the vector space, but this technically need not be included as an axiom as it can be proven from the eight mentioned previously)